# Can the STFT decrease arbitrarily quickly near the origin?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

For $f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ we can define the Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT) $V_gf \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$ as $$V_gf(x, \omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f \overline{g(t - x)} e^{-2 \pi i t \cdot \omega}dt.$$

Suppose we fix $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d), f \neq 0, K \in \mathbb{N},$ and $R \in \mathbb{R}.$ Is it possible to find $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so that $|V_gf| < \frac{|\langle f, g \rangle|}{K}$ outside a ball of radius $R$ around the origin?

EDIT: By applying time-frequency shifts to $g$ we can assume that a max of $|V_gf(x, \omega)|$ occurs at the origin $V_gf(0,0) = \langle f, g \rangle$. It seems potentially advantageous to us to shift $g$ in this way, but that is only a suggestion and there is no requirement that $|V_gf|$ have a max at the origin.

Note that for any fixed $g$ there is an $R$ which will suffice, as $V_gf \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^{2d}).$ I am interested in the case where we take $R \to 0$ (say along the sequence $R_k = \frac{1}{k}$) and try to find a sequence $g_k$ so that each $g_k$ satisfies the inequality for the radius $R_k.$

If it helps to assume that $f$ is a Schwartz function so that we can let $g$ be a distribution then I would be interested in this case as well.

Comment: Just to be sure: In the last sentence, you want to choose $g$ such that $V_g f(0,0) = \langle f,g\rangle = \max |V_g f|>0$ also holds? Moreover, what is the meaning of that $0\in\mathbb{N}$? Finally, $f\equiv 0$ should be excluded.

Comment: Edited the post to try to clarify my intent. We do not need $|V_gf|$ to have a  max at the origin, that was only a suggestion.